# ORACLE : Return Distinct Values with Comma

Tags: sql, oracle, regexp-replace, listagg

I have a table with two columns label and location.

```
Label                        Location
---------------------------------------
OLR-2873-SSA/GTA              GTA

OLR-2873-SSA/GTA              GTA

OLR-2873-SSA/POW              POW

OLR-2873-SSA/POWGTA           POWGTA
```

I want output to be like

```
Lable                                                     Location 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
OLR-2873-SSA/GTA,OLR-2873-SSA/POW,OLR-2873-SSA/POWGTA      GTA,POW,POWGTA
```

I want to use the  regular expressions and get he output.

I tried

```
Select 
dbms_lob.substr( ltrim(REGEXP_REPLACE(REPLACE(
         REPLACE(
           XMLAGG(
             XMLELEMENT("A",label )
               ORDER BY label).getClobVal(),
             '<A>',','),
             '</A>',''),'([^,]+)(,\1)+', '\1'),
                  ','),4000,1) label , dbms_lob.substr( ltrim(REGEXP_REPLACE(REPLACE(
         REPLACE(
           XMLAGG(
             XMLELEMENT("A",location )
               ORDER BY location).getClobVal(),
             '<A>',','),
             '</A>',''),'([^,]+)(,\1)+', '\1'),
                  ','),4000,1) LOCATION from table_name.
```

But I get the output like this

```
Label                                  Location
----------------
OLR-2873-SSA/GTA,OLR-2873-SSA/POWGTA   GTA,POWGTA
```

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft SQL Version

```
DECLARE @Table AS TABLE (Label VARCHAR(25), Location VARCHAR(25))

INSERT INTO @Table (Label, Location) VALUES ('OLR-2873-SSA/GTA','GTA')
   ,('OLR-2873-SSA/GTA','GTA')
   ,('OLR-2873-SSA/POW','POW')
   ,('OLR-2873-SSA/POWGTA','POWGTA')

SELECT
    Label = STUFF(
        (SELECT ',' + Label
        FROM
            @Table t
        FOR XML PATH(''))
        ,1,1,'')
    ,Location = STUFF(
        (SELECT ',' + Location
        FROM
            @Table t
        FOR XML PATH(''))
        ,1,1,'')
```

Basically you appear to be looking for a concatenation of strings in rows, there are a few ways if you look around the internet.  One way I use is converting the rows to an xml string with a comma prefacing the value and no column name, then use stuff to tidy up the first comma. So the `FOR XML PATH('')` basically means no root element, then because there is no column name you won't get the other xml tags either e.g. no `<label></label>`. Adding the delimiter to the value of the column you now have a long delimited string that you just need to get rid of the first unneeded delimiter.

Comment: I want the answer in Oracle.

Comment: Ahhh I see the tag now perhaps specifying in the question would be good too. I will leave it around in case someone else was looking for MS version.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
WITH TEST_DATA AS (
    SELECT 'OLR-2873-SSA/GTA' AS LABEL, 'GTA' AS LOCATION FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'OLR-2873-SSA/GTA' AS LABEL, 'GTA' AS LOCATION FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'OLR-2873-SSA/POW' AS LABEL, 'POW' AS LOCATION FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'OLR-2873-SSA/POWGTA' AS LABEL, 'POWGTA' AS LOCATION FROM DUAL
)
SELECT
    LISTAGG(CASE LABEL_DISTINCT WHEN 1 THEN LABEL END, ',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY 0) AS LABEL,
    LISTAGG(CASE LOCATION_DISTINCT WHEN 1 THEN LOCATION END, ',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY 0) AS LOCATION
FROM (
    SELECT
        LABEL,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY LABEL ORDER BY 0) AS LABEL_DISTINCT,
        LOCATION,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY LOCATION ORDER BY 0) AS LOCATION_DISTINCT
    FROM
        TEST_DATA
)
```